# react-apollo Network error: Server response was missing for query 'Hello'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to set up react-apollo using this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { ApolloProvider, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';


const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});



class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p> Hello React project</p>;  }
}
const MY_QUERY = gql`query Hello { hello }`;

const AppWithData = graphql(MY_QUERY)(App)
render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <AppWithData />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

However, I get this error:
[image]

Looking at the Network tab in chrome dev tools, I can see that the request is coming through:
[image]

I am wondering if maybe I am missing some configuration setting to get the responses in the right format?  Or maybe I need to return the data from my graphql endpoint in a different format?  Any advice is appreciated, I am just learning graphql and apollo so it could be something super obvious.  thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to wrap the response in a 'data' key, so the response I needed was:

```
{
    "data": {
         "hello": "hello"
    }   
}
```

As I said, I am brand new to graphql/apollo